# What are different ways of using a phrasal verb “put over” in giving different meaning?

Tags: prepositions

When I look up in a dictionary,The verb “put over” has three different meaning. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put%20over

1. Delay or postpone
2. Communicate effectively
3. to achieve or carry through by deceit or trickery.

I’m more concerned with the the first meaning it gives and uses preposition. I even found some where it doesn’t use preposition. Examples:

> Alex put the discussion over until tomorrow. (tomorrow is followed by until)

> I put it over Sunday. (Sunday is not followed by preposition)

Here, in such cases what are other possible prepositions that can be used.

Similarly, with the second meaning it gives,

> Abraham put his idea over to the reader. (“to” has been used)

And with the third meaning it gives,

> Dealership put the price over him. (has the deceit or trickery been achieved?)

Would you please give me an appropriate structures in each cases followed by appropriate preposition?

Comment: How about "put the ball over the fence"?

Comment: Would you please explain a bit in each case ?